# How to store the rows that have been added to a datagridview to a datarow array in C#?

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, datatable, dataset

I am using the following code to fill a datagridview with rows from a datatable.
        private void FillEmpEmer()
        {
            int emerNo;

```
        empEmerDT.Columns.Add("Emergency Number", typeof(string));
        empEmerDT.Columns.Add("Emergency Address", typeof(string));

        empEmerRows = EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpEmer"].Select("EmpID='" + txt_EmpID.Text + "'");
        foreach (DataRow dR in empEmerRows)
        {
            emerNo = Convert.ToInt32(dR[1]);
            emerRows = EmpInfoDS.Tables["Emer"].Select("EmerNo='" + emerNo + "'");

            empEmerDT.Rows.Add(emerNo, emerRows[0][1]);
        }

          dataGrid_Emer.DataSource = null;
          dataGrid_Emer.DataSource = empEmerDT.DefaultView;
    }
```

How do I store the new Rows that have been added to the datagridview into a new DATAROW array ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of DataTable's GetChanges method to get a reference to the DataRows that has been added.

It's like this:

```
DataTable changeTable = table.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
```